Chromecast not playing protected files
I have an HTML5 player with the chromecast streaming option in the controlbar. Some files it plays are on a different domain that has file protection enabled and permissions enabled for my domain so the mp4's play. Everything works until you use the chromecast option. Then the files are blocked and won't play on the tv.
Does anyone know why? I'm wondering if chromecast uses a domain alias before streaming to the tv and if so, what domain alias does it use? Is there a way to find out?
